# JavaScript radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few `radio` buttons, and when I select one of them, I also have to check another one.

For example, if I select *yes* on a `radio` button, another `radio` button must be automatically checked with *no*.
I tried a few scripts but don't seem to work.

Does anyone know a solution? I'm new in JS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To respect standards only one radio button in each group should be checked at a time.

Comment: @Stranger_in_the_night, maybe the radio buttons are in different `name`s.

Comment: Yeah sounds like 2 sets of options to me a Yes/No and another Yes/No... hunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [***`>　Live Demo　<`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ePD9k/2/)

---

```
<!--HTML-->
<input type="radio" name="group_1" value="yes" id="r1">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group_1" value="no" id="r2">No<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group_2" value="yes" id="r3">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group_2" value="no" id="r4">No<br>​

//Script
$("input[name='group_1']").click(function(){
    if(this.value=="yes"){
        $("input#r4").attr("checked",true);
    }else{
        $("input#r3").attr("checked",true);
    }
});
$("input[name='group_2']").click(function(){
    if(this.value=="yes"){
        $("input#r2").attr("checked",true);
    }else{
        $("input#r1").attr("checked",true);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This one works for me. If I'll have other problems with this I'll post here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very certain on what you are trying to achieve but by using the "name" attribute this automatically happens...when you check one radio...the others with the same name get set to unchecked.

```
<input type="radio" name="someoption" value="0" />0 
<input type="radio" name="someoption" value="1" />1 
<input type="radio" name="someoption" value="2" />2
```

checking any one of the above will cause the other 2 to be unchecked

unless do you may be mean checkboxes or multiple option sets ?

Comment: @WaseemSabjee You should better edit this answer instead of posting another one. Didn't you see the warning message when you click "Add Another Answer"?

Comment: I considered this a prompt for clarification...my apologies if it was taken wrong way...no need for politics.

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
$('#myradio1').bind('change', function () {
  $('#myradio3').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

html

```
<input type="radio" name="cols1" value="1" id="myradio1" />
<input type="radio" name="cols1" value="2" id="myradio2" />
<input type="radio" name="cols2" value="1" id="myradio3" />
<input type="radio" name="cols2" value="2" id="myradio4" />
```

see working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9jXbv/

Answer (score 0):

For HTML markup like below:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="yes"> yes
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="no"> no
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="yes"> yes
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="no"> no
</div>
```

you can use this JavaScript code:

```
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
    var that = this;
    $(":radio").filter(function() {
        return this.value == "no" && this.name != that.name;
    }).prop("checked", true);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nKLMX/

Comment: `I have a few radio buttons, and when I select one of them, I also have to check another one.` When I click on `no` in your demo, it doesn't select the `yes`s... :/

Comment: @Derek, and should it select 'yes'? Think logically, 'yes' means 'no' to others but 'no' doesn't mean 'yes' to others. That's why I didn't add this functionality.

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure what he really wants to do in his question.

Comment: @Derek So am I. Let's see which solution is the most suitable. If my perceptions are wrong, I will simply remove an answer and fix the problem with it :)

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
​$("#radio1").change(function() {
    $("#radio2").removeAttr("checked");
});​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I've mocked up a pure JS solution to this ( No libraries )

```
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="1" />Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="0" />No
<br /><br />
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="1" />Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="0" />No

<script type="text/javascript">
    var g1 = document.getElementsByName('g1'); // store g1 elements
    var g2 = document.getElementsByName('g2'); // store g2 elements

    // handle click functionality
    function radio_checked_event(obj, f) {
        if(obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener('click', f, false);
        } else if(obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent('onclick', f);
        }
    }

    // when you click on g1 yes
    radio_checked_event(g1[0], function() {
            //set g1 no to checked
        g2[1].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    });
</script>
```